# Permissions about Saving files to an SD card

Tags: sd-card

I am having trouble while saving valuable pdf files to my `16GB SDcard`.  I can save just fine on my system hard drive, but every time I try to move it to the SD card or save it straight to there, it gives me a `insufficient permissions` message at the bottom of my screen.

I'd like to have these files on the SD card for so I can move them from system to system.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the message? And the output of `sudo mount` while the card is plugged.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the equivalent of `media\yourusername` and right click onto the sd card and open properties, then the permissions tab :

[image: Properties]

Modify the permissions, and enable the read-write option, that is "Create and Delete Files" on all the user s and user group options